# Version Control advice

Tags: version-control, mercurial, lamp, bitbucket

We've decided on a version control system - using Mercurial clients and Bitbucket for repositories. But it's just occurred to me we have a problem I didn't consider.

We have an internal development LAMP server (Ubuntu) and all the developers work on websites stored on it, which means all developers share a single file source and we are all working from it. It's rare that two different developers will work on the same site at the some time, but it does happen occasionally. This means that two developers can easily overwrite each others work if they are working on the same file at the same time.

So my questions is: what is the best solution to this problem? Bearing in mind we like the convenience of a single internal server so that we can demo sites internally, and it also has a cron job running for backing up the files and databases.

I am guessing each developer would have to run their own LAMP (or WAMP) servers on their individual workstations, commit, and push to bitbucket repository. And of course whenever working on a different site, do a pull and resolve any differences as per usual. This of course takes away the convenience of other team members (non developers) being able to browse to 192.168.0.100 (the LAMP server IP address) and looking at the progress of websites, not to mention that some clients can also access the same server externally (I've set up a port forward and limited to their IP addresses) to see the progress of their websites too.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the better solution is probably to set each developer up with a local server.  It may seem inconvenient to you because you're apparently used to sharing a server, but consider:

1. If you're really interested in using a single server as a demo server, it's probably better that people aren't actively working developing on it at the time.  They could break stuff that way!  And developers shouldn't have to worry about breaking stuff when they're developing.  Developing often means experimenting.
2. Having each developer running their own server will give them flexibility to, say, work disconnected.  You've got a decentralized version control system (mercurial), but your development process is highly centralized.  Even if you don't want people to work remotely, realize that when your single server goes down now, *everybody goes down*.
3. Any time a developer commits and pushes those commits, you can automate deployment directly to your demo site.  That way, you still have a quite up-to-date source on your demo server.

**TL;DR: Keep the demo server, but let your devs work on their own servers.**

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. It'd be good if we could use the internal server for repositories to push too. Would be faster!

Comment: Miker, pushing is not that slow.  You can set up bitbucket such that when someone pushes to it, the code is copied to your staging server right away.  We're talking seconds, not minutes here.  But don't think that means you should commit+push just to preview your changes on the demo server.  You should not!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you have to **seriously re-think** about used workflow, because LAMP-per-dev is only *slightly* better than editing sites in-place

- I can't see place for Bitbucket in serious corporate development - in-house resources are at least more manageable
- I can't see reasons don't use Staging Mercurial-server (pseudo-central) with Staging internal LAMP-server (which you have and use now)

I can imagine at least two possible choices (fast, dirty, draft idea, not ready-to-use solution), both are [hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html)-based

### Less manageable, faster for implement

Every developer have in own local repo hook, which after (each?) commit export his tip and copy exported to related site space. Workflow: commit - test results on internal site

Advantages: easy, fast to implement

Disadvantages: Can't prevent (due to distributed nature) overwriting of tested code by code from another developer

### Manageable deploy, harder to implement and manage

LAMP-server become also Mercurial-server, which hosts "central" clones of all site-repos, updated by push only from developer local repo. Each repo on this server must get two hooks:

- "before-push" checks, is it allowed to push now, or site "locked" by previous developer
- "post-push", which export-copy received data and perform also control function for hook 1: based on conditions (subject of discussion) lock/unlock pushes to repo

Workflow: commit - push - test results - tag WC with special (moved) tag - commit tag - push unlocking changeset into repo

Advantages: manageable single-point testing

Disadvantages: possible delays due to push-workflow and blocking of pushes. The need to install, configure, support additional server. Complexity of changegroup and pretxnchangegroup hooks

**Final notes and hints for solution 2:** I *think* (**not tested**), special tag (with -f for movement across changesets) can be used as unlock sign (bookmark will not satisfy condition "move by hand"). I.e - developer commit (and pushes) non-tagged changeset, tag (f.e) "Passed" mark some older changeset. When testing results on Staging server is done, developer tag WC with the above tag, commit tag and pushed to central repo. changegroup hook must detect pushing of .hgtags and (in some-way) allow future data-pushes (control-pushes must be allowed always)